# CSV format of Snowflake UI Download Results doesn't enclose values with newline character into quotation marks

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that contains string values with new-line character.

```
id    value
0       a
1       b
        c
2       d
```

In my example, the second row holds value `b\nc`.

When I query the data from a Worksheet, the data is displayed correctly. However when I'm downloading the results in a CSV format using Download or View Results button, the values that contain the new-line character aren't enclosed in quotation marks.

What I expect:

```
id, value
0, a
1, "b
c"
2, d
```

and this would be read by Excel correctly. What I get is

```
0,a
1,b
c
2,d
```

Is there a way to make Snowflake enclose fields containing `\n` into quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just did a test and it works as you are expecting - Snowflake adds the value with the newline inside quotes when you download as a CSV. If you are testing this by opening the file in Excel then that's probably what's causing your issue.

Never check what a CSV file looks like by opening it in Excel, always open it in a text editor. Excel does not accurately represent the contents of a file. Excel does things like remove quotes etc. Also, if you then save the file in Excel, it actually changes the file's contents which confuses people even more when they re-open it in a text editor.

Here is my test:

```sql
-- Create a sample table with two columns
create or replace table test_db.public.test_table (col1 number, col2 varchar);

-- Insert three rows into the table. The middle one has a \n
insert overwrite into test_db.public.test_table values (0, 'a'), (1, 'b 
c'), (2, 'd');

-- Select all from the table and then Download the results as a CSV
select * from test_db.public.test_table;
```

If I go to where the file downloads to and check its contents (by opening it with Sublime Text instead of Excel) it looks like this:

```
COL1,COL2
0,a
1,"b 
c"
2,d
```

You can see that the second row contains the quoted characters.

Comment: You're right, it's all good with the "\n" character. My example was wrong, my text contains "\r" character, not the "\n" character, and that one is written to the csv file without quotation. I'm not sure if "\r" should be enclosed in quotation, I'll just replace it with "\n"